# SSIS Package not updating a column

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a table thats being pulled from a different server. The table was missing a column that was added later so I updated my SSIS Package to bring in the column. The SSIS worked fine the first time around but now I've scheduled it to run and though the columns are mapped correctly the new column isnt being populated. When I create a new SSIS package it runs and populates the field but soon as the SSIS Package is scheduled the column is not being updated. Please advise what could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The path in SQL Agent Job Step is not correct or you not correctly saved SSIS package.

1. If SSIS package in SQL agent runing from File system, you must build package - Menu->Build->Build[package name]
2. if SSIS package is runing from SSISDB you must deploy package in server.

Comment: I am running the SSIS Package using the task scheduler and a BAT file

Comment: Which file you using Packagedierctory->PackageNamedirectory->dtsx or  Packagedierctory->PackageNamedirectory->bin->dtsx